# How to exclude integer ranges when selecting elements from a list in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm currently writing an app that pulls a certain number of flight records. The following code is functioning correctly:

```
        foreach (var rec in record
            .Skip(GetFlightIndex())
            .Take((int)AppDefaults.NumFlights))
```

Now, I would like to exclude flight records with flight numbers that fall within certain ranges (i.e. Charter Flights etc.) For some reason, this code is not working. Any thoughts on why that might be?

```
        foreach(var rec in records
            .Skip(GetFlightIndex())
            .Take((int)AppDefaults.NumFlights)
            .Where( i =>
                Int32.Parse(i.FLIGHTNO) < 700 && Int32.Parse(i.FLIGHTNO) > 799 &&
                Int32.Parse(i.FLIGHTNO) < 900 && Int32.Parse(i.FLIGHTNO) > 999 &&
                Int32.Parse(i.FLIGHTNO) < 1900 && Int32.Parse(i.FLIGHTNO) > 1999 &&
                Int32.Parse(i.FLIGHTNO) < 8000 && Int32.Parse(i.FLIGHTNO) > 9799 &&
                Int32.Parse(i.FLIGHTNO) < 9900 && Int32.Parse(i.FLIGHTNO) > 9999 ))
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic in the where clause is not quite right. The following can never be true:

```
Int32.Parse(i.FLIGHTNO) < 700 && Int32.Parse(i.FLIGHTNO) > 799
```

You probably meant:

```
Int32.Parse(i.FLIGHTNO) > 700 && Int32.Parse(i.FLIGHTNO) < 799
```

Additionally, a number could never be between 700-799 **AND** 900-999.. So you will want an OR between each range.

```
Int32.Parse((i.FLIGHTNO) > 700 && Int32.Parse(i.FLIGHTNO) < 799) ||
Int32.Parse((i.FLIGHTNO) > 900 && Int32.Parse(i.FLIGHTNO) < 999) ||
Int32.Parse((i.FLIGHTNO) > 1900 && Int32.Parse(i.FLIGHTNO) < 1999) ||
Int32.Parse((i.FLIGHTNO) > 8000 && Int32.Parse(i.FLIGHTNO) < 9799) ||
Int32.Parse((i.FLIGHTNO) > 9900 && Int32.Parse(i.FLIGHTNO) < 9999)
```

Finally, you probably want to filter, then get the page's data, not the other way around as you have it -- get the page data then filter. To change this move the `Where()` before the `Skip()`

Comment: Thanks for catching me on this, I actually meant to exclude those ranges so this logic finally worked: Int32.Parse(i.FLIGHTNO) < 700 || Int32.Parse(i.FLIGHTNO) > 799 && ...